# Send an Intent from a foreground Activity to another one without closing it

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'd like to pass some data from a foreground activity to another that is currently in background.

I know that I can use setResult()/onActivityResult() and startActivity()/getIntent() to send an Intent with data while an Activity opens/closes, but in this case this does not seem to be usable.

Is there any way other than using static methods or fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BroadcastReceiver (registering it in onCreate and unregistering it in onDestroy) was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sharedpreferences to store the data

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done what you are trying to do, but I think you may want to investigate Handlers and message passing...